# Is there any function available for printing some characters instead of whole strings?

Tags: c

see

```
char str[] = "hello world";
printf("%s",str);
```

printf statement prints the all character in string before reaching `'\0'`

so what if i want to print just 4 1st character of `str` on `stdout`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just specify the field width in the printf format string:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *s = "Hello world !";

    printf("%.4s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

or, if you want to specify the field width at run-time:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *s = "Hello world !";
    const int fw = 4;

    printf("%.*s\n", fw, s);
    return 0;
}
```

In either case the output will be:

```
Hell
```

Comment: oh its working i have did the same things but i was missing . after % so it was not working...!!

Answer (score 2):

For the first *character,* you can just use:

```
printf ("%c", *str);         // or
printf ("%c", *(str+0));     // or
printf ("%c", str[0]);
```

For a different character, just reach out and grab it by using an offset. For the second `l` at offset 3:

```
printf ("%c", str[3]);       // or
printf ("%c", *(str+3));
```

For a substring, you can use a combination of that method along with the maximum field width feature of `printf`:

```
printf ("%.2s", str+3);      // prints "lo"
```

With *all* these solutions, you want to make sure you don't start on the wrong side of the null terminator. That wouldn't be a good thing :-)

If you want a generalised solution that will work for any string, and is relatively safe in terms of finding the starting point, you can use:

```
void outSubstr (FILE *fh, char *str, size_t start, size_t sz, int padOut) {
    if (start >= strlen (str)) {
        if (padOut)
            fprintf (fh, "%*s", sz, "");
        return;
    }

    if (padOut)
        fprintf (fh, "%-*.*s", sz, sz, str + start);
    else
        fprintf (fh, "%-.*s", sz, str + start);
}
```

The parameters are as follows:

- `fh` is the file handle to write to.
- `str` is the start of the string.
- `start` is the offset to start printing from.
- `sz` is the maximum number of characters to print.
- `padOut` is a flag indicating that `sz` is also the *minimum* size. Output will be padded with spaces on the right if there are not enough characters in the string to satisfy the size.

Answer (score 2):

You can use %c in your format string:

```
printf("%c", *s);
```

prints 'H'

To print an arbitrary char:

```
printf("%c", s[3]);
```

prints 'l'

Answer (score 1):

This will print up to 4 characters.

```
printf("%.4s", str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
there is also a "substr()" function 

that return the substring from complete string.

example
printf("%s",substr(str,0,4));

it has syntax like this

substr(arrayName,charStartingPosition, lengthOfCharacters);

i hope this is easy to understand and no need to write more than 1 statement.
```

Answer (score 0):

Really less painful for the system :

```
int main(void)
{
  char c;

  c = 'z';
  write(1, &c, 1);
}
```

No need for heavy stdio here

Then you can ...

```
char *s = "Hello, World!";
write(1, s, numberOfChars);
```

Or if you really want to do it char by char:

```
void printnchars(char *s, int n)
{
  int i;

  i = 0;
  while (i <= n)
  {
    write(1, s + i, 1);
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Other than the fact that there is no `write` in ISO C :-) Perhaps you meant `fputc`?

Answer (score -1):

```
numOfChars = 4;
printf("%.*s\n", numOfChars, "Hello, world!");
```

Where `numOfChars` is the quantity of characters that you want to print.

Comment: I'm _assuming_ that my edit is what you meant. You can't put the variable directly in the string itself, you have to use `*`.

Comment: Yes, it is. "Jumping" from a programming language to others makes me always confuse. Sorry.

Comment: No probs, I once got an error in some Perl code I was developing and, when I investigated, I'd coded up an entire function in Python :-) Damn embarrassing.